# Objective C: How to implement 'auto complete' feature (like google search)

Tags: objective-c, ios, autocomplete

I want to implement a search with a auto-complete feature (like google search) as seen in the screenshot below:

For example if I key auto, a list of results starting or containing auto will be displayed in the table

[image]

Are there any tutorials or resources available for my reference?

Comment: It will depend on where your data comes from. There are some WWDC videos (2010 I think) which mention how to do it for CoreData. Where is your data coming from? CoreData or the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just an internal set of string you want autocompletion for, i.e. you are not trying to dynamically fetch them from the internet. Then I have created a class which I have put up on GitHub that wil turn every string that begins with a string, for example, @"cat" would return {@"cat", @"catalog", @"category"}.

[NDTrie](http://github.com/nathanday/ndtrie)