# google suggest like feature in ios

Tags: ios

First things first, I am very new to ios development. I am very much experienced with web dev though.

I have gone through [How to implement 'auto complete' feature (like google search)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978667/objective-c-how-to-implement-auto-complete-feature-like-google-search), but unfortunately it is only applicable for local data.

I have to implement similar feature but the data will have to be brought from a remote server. 
 I will be using [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

So, I am left with two problems

1. Parse the response JSON and display it as list below the text box
2. The list items must be interactable. If i click any of those a corresponding data will be retrived.

Any leads on this will be very appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parsing the JSON you can use [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit). It generates a NSDictionary from your JSON Data

For accessing the list items look at the [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) Reference under `– tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Maybe [this tutorial](http://ygamretuta.me/2011/08/10/ios-implementing-a-basic-search-uisearchdisplaycontroller-and-interface-builder/) will help you implementing a UISearchdispayController which I really recommend for such functionality.

Comment: it appears you do not have to use third party JSON libraries. io5 has built in support for JSON

Comment: Yes you are right, and I know that ;) But I think it's a great and easy to use lib so I recommended it here.

Answer (score 0):

ios5 has built in [support for JSON.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) It is very easy to use and is native so future compatibility isn't an issue.

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
```